# How to set up Camera orientation in Landscape mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need one help form You end, I am implementing one camera project as well, i have to make take picture in Landscape mode only, i don't want  portrait mode, i am not able to view lands cape mode, always in portrait mode only, i cannot change lands cape mode, How to change oreaintaion, Any idea,

This is the i am using controller,

```
CameraController? controller;
 controller = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
      androidUseOpenGL: useOpenGL,
      
    );

  //UI
 return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 7,
      //  aspectRatio: controller!.value.previewSize!.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller!),
    );
```

This is the controller i am using for camera purpose,I cannot change in Landscape mode, how to do, is any have any Idea , Please comment, it would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide complete use case of the Screen in which you are using cameraPreview ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CameraController? controller;

// Initialize the CameraController with landscape orientation
controller = CameraController(
  cameraDescription,
  ResolutionPreset.high, // Choose an appropriate resolution preset
  enableAudio: enableAudio,
  androidUseOpenGL: useOpenGL,
);

// UI
return RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1, // Rotate by 90 degrees clockwise for landscape orientation
  child: CameraPreview(controller!),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use quarterTurns property to move camera orientation.

```
RotatedBox(
    quarterTurns: 1, // Adjust this value as per your needed
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: CameraPreview(controller),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1, // Rotate preview to landscape
  child: CameraPreview(controller!),
),
```

If you need to handle potential orientation changes (e.g., during app backgrounding/foregrounding), consider using the OrientationBuilder widget to adapt UI elements based on the device's current orientation. However, this might not be strictly necessary if you've locked the orientation.

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      // Landscape UI
    } else {
      // Handle potential portrait mode (if not locked)
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [OrientationBuilder](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation) to get the active orientation of the device
2. Update the **quarterTurns** as needed

```dart
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    // set the turn as per requirement
    final turn = orientation == Orientation.landscape ? 2: 1; // set the turn as per requirement
    RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: turn,
      child: CameraPreview(controller!),
    ),
  },
),
```